# Promiscuous Network Card and PCI

Tags: linux, computer-building, thinkcentre

What PCI NIC supports Promiscuous?? I' having a hard time looking for one , I'm planning to set it up in a Lenovo Think Centre hardware

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Your question looks like a product recommendation which means it will probably be closed, however,you could try editing it to something like "How can I tell if a NIC supports promiscuous mode?".

Comment: This question is off-topic – we do not do shopping recommendations. Please see [help/on-topic]


Answer (score 2):

I've yet to come across a NIC that does NOT support promiscuous mode !! I wonder if the problem you are having is that you are connecting to a switch rather then a hub, and thus not seeing any traffic ?

FWIW, Intel specifically markets the [Intel Pro](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-004185.htm) cards as supporting promiscuous mode.  No doubt there are plenty others (probably any network card), but the first care I came across in this range was [this](http://www.intel.com/products/desktop/adapters/pro1000gt/pro1000gt-overview.htm) one.    Again though, pretty much any card will do this.

Comment: if that's the case, that they all do, then perhaps he didn't realise it 'cos it requires some software to set it so, there being no native option in windows.  This from the intel site(confirming what you say and mentioning about software) "Yes, all currently marketed Intel® PRO/100, Intel® PRO/1000, Intel® Gigabit, Intel® PRO/10 Gigabit, and Intel® 10 Gigabit adapters support Promiscuous mode. A network management agent or other software (such as "Network sniffer") is required to tell the OS to turn on the promiscuous mode support. Users cannot enable or disable the support."